# is Xcode installation mandatory for "React Native CLI"?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm learning React Native and got to know about 2 options available namely Expo CLI & React Native CLI

My query is, if installation of Xcode is mandatory for using React Native CLI ?

Comment: If you want to run, test and and build for ios devices, yes it is mandatory. But if you're going to just run and build for android, you don't need to install xcode.

Answer (score 1):

xCode and android studio is mandatory for Bare React Native Apps (with React Native CLI or Expo Bare Workflow).

With an expo Managed workflow app there is no need to install android studio and xCode.

You can learn more on expo:
https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/